# How to prevent buttons getting double clicked in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

There are several occasions that users try to click a button multiple times in a row for whatever reason.

I want to disable or hide a button for a few seconds after it is clicked, so that it will not be clicked again temporarily.

By buttons here I mean every button in Odoo that is possible to implement this feature.

Is there a solution to achieve such mechanism?

If there is no system-wide implementation for this, a button-specific method will suffice.

Comment: Very good question, but i fear it's a lifetime quest to achieve it. Usually i would open up an issue on github for it and ping the frontend team, to atleast get a hint if it's possible and where to start the journey ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#yourbutton").on('click', function (event) {  
               event.preventDefault();
               //your js code
               //to disable the button:
               $(this).prop('disabled', true);
         });
    });
```